# Get type name of object and property name?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I need function, that returns {obj type name}.{property name}.{property name}..
For example:

```
class City {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class Country {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public City MyCity {get;set;}
}

var myCountry = new Country() { 
    Name="Ukraine",
    MyCity = new City() {
        Name = "Kharkov"
    }
}
```

So my function should return **"{Country.Name}" or "{Country.MyCity.Name}"** depends on input parameter. What is the way to do it?

Comment: COuld you show how input affect on the output? What is your input?

Comment: Cuong Le, when "myCountry.Name" then "{Country}.{Name}", when "myCountry.MyCity.Name" then "{Country}.{MyCity}.{Name}", did it make sens?

Comment: Better you show method definition what is your input and what is our output

Answer (score 2):

Use .net reflection

http://www.codersource.net/microsoftnet/cbasicstutorials/cnettutorialreflection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post much info on the requirement but, if you know your object type then there is no need to use Reflection, you can test with `is` like this:

```
if(returnCity && myObject is Country) //I'm assuming that the input value is boolean but, you get the idea...
{
    return myObject.City.Name;
}
else
{
    return myObject.Name;
}
```

Now, if you want to use Reflection, you can do something among these lines:

```
public static string GetNameFrom( object myObject )
{
    var t = myObject.GetType();
    if( t == typeof(Country) )
    {
        return ((Country)myObject).City.Name;
    }

    return ((City)myObject).Name;
}
```

Or, a more generic approach:

```
static string GetNameFrom( object myObject )
{
    var type = myObject.GetType();
    var city = myObject.GetProperty( "City" );
    if( city != null)
    {
        var cityVal = city.GetValue( myObject, null );
        return (string)cityVal.GetType().GetProperty( "Name" ).GetValue( cityVal, null );
    }

    return (string)type.GetProperty( "Name" ).GetValue( myObject, null );
}
```

Comment: Not me who just voted you down without a comment, but this an approach of last resort. If avoiding reflection was desired, then an Interface or an attribute would be better design and way more future proof

Comment: Totally agree with you but, judging from the question i gave him a "simple" solution, may be all that he needs...

Comment: There's some people on this site who are a bit quick off the mark on the downvote thing. Might be wise to beef it up with this is the quick and dirty approach. Seeing as there's enough here to constitute an answer, I pushed you all the way back to a flat zero :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an IPrintable facade and use a recursive function Print(). Try to catch the idea and modify code for your concrete task. Hope, my example will be helpfull for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    interface IPrintable
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    class City : IPrintable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Country : IPrintable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public City MyCity { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myCountry = new Country()
            {
                Name = "Ukraine",
                MyCity = new City()
                 {
                     Name = "Kharkov"
                 }
            };

            Console.WriteLine(Print(myCountry, @"{{{0}}}"));
            Console.WriteLine(Print(new City()
            {
                Name = "New-York"
            }, @"{{{0}}}"));
        }

        private static string Print(IPrintable printaleObject, string formatter)
        {
            foreach (var prop in printaleObject.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                object val = prop.GetValue(printaleObject, null);
                if (val is IPrintable)
                {
                    return String.Format(formatter, printaleObject.Name) + Print((IPrintable)val, formatter);
                }
            }
            return String.Format(formatter, printaleObject.Name);
        }
    }
}
```